# .htaccess Internal Server Error: ErrorDocument not working (RewriteEngine on)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Whenever I have RewriteEngine on my ErrorDocument - part is not working.
This is my current .htacces file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 404.php

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /$1.php [QSA,L]
```

So when I open a not existing file in my browser, I get a 500 Internal Server Error and I am not getting redirected to the 404.php - file.

Please help me ;)

Comment: Did you check your server's error log?

Comment: Is the 500 ISE happening on files in the root, in a subdirectory or both?

Comment: @Maerlyn Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: @JasonS it is happening on root. I have never tested it in a subdirecotry.

Comment: Your 404 ErrorDocument directive is fine.  It's the rewrite condition on the last line that's causing problems... redirecting endlessly.   See @Maerlyn comment for a log excerpt.

Comment: @Pagerange do you know how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're blindly rewriting the `.php` to the end of the URI. Let's take a look to see what happens when you go to a 404 URL:

- you request: `http://example.com/blahblah`
- The URI is not a file (passes `!-f`)
- The URI is not a directory (passes `!-d`)
- The URI matches `(.*)`.
- The URI gets rewritten to include a `.php`
- The URI is now `/blahblah.php`
- The URI is not a file (passes `!-f`)
- The URI is not a directory (passes `!-d`)
- The URI matches `(.*)`.
- The URI gets rewritten to include a `.php`
- The URI is now `/blahblah.php.php`
- The URI is not a file (passes `!-f`)
- The URI is not a directory (passes `!-d`)
- The URI matches `(.*)`.
- The URI gets rewritten to include a `.php`
- The URI is now `/blahblah.php.php.php`

etc.

You need to make sure what you're rewriting to actually exists or you cause a loop:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /$1.php [QSA,L]
```